# Base64 decode leads to partial decode followed by non printable characters

Tags: character-encoding, base64, urlencode, base64url

We are trying to decode base64 encoded strings from some scraped URLs. However the decoding works only partially and starts generating non-printable characters. For example,

Here is the encoded string

```
CiQ2MmE5NzI5NC01YTJhLTQzMTctOTU2Yi1lY2E3MjU3NzA2ZWEQyIgCGISAAiIDQ1BBKM609E8whIACOZhn42doAQAAQg10X3NyeGhsODZ2emxnSgJJRFIGQ2hyb21lWgxNb2JpbGUgUGhvbmViB0FuZHJvaWRqeGh0dHBzOi8vcmV2dHRtb2JpbGUuY29tL2NsaWNrLnBocD9rZXk9ZGEyZ3luNGc3bnZtanM4MDk0YWEmQ1BDPXtDUEN9JkNBTVBBSUdOX0lEPXtDQU1QQUlHTl9JRH0mQ1JFQVRJVkVfSUQ9e0NSRUFUSVZFX0lEfXIeCMaUMxD29gEYosk_IPb2ASgAMgYwLjAwNzBAAEgigAGIrpGwB4gB-o7B4wWSAQ8xMTguMTM2LjE1NC4yMjaaAQ8xMTguMTM2LjE1NC4yMjaiAQxKYWthcnRhIFJheWE=
```

the decoded output looks like this

```
    i'$fpo%?
$62a97294-5a2a-4317-956b-eca7257706ea"CPA(O09gghB
t_srxhl86vzlgJIDRChromeZMobile PhonebAndroidjxhttps://revttmobile.com/click.php?key=da2gyn4g7nvmjs8094aa&CPC={CPC}&CAMPAIGN_ID={CAMPAIGN_ID}&CREATIVE_ID={CREATIVE_ID}r3=J
b+lh0Y 3bSB##i3bSB##j 'F&
```

So we are able to get partial data but not everything. Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: This base64 string contains binary data.

Comment: The data that was base64 encoded clearly consists of more than just simple text. It appears to have some binary elements to it as well